# How to remove auth request in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image]

This message says: `Required authorization. To access on the server http://localhhost:8080 you should enter login and password. Server message: Spring`.

I'm using Hibernate 4, Spring 4 and Gradle. Also, I'm using Spring Boot. But this message appears even if I have got plane code from [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/). What caused it and how to get rid of it? What's wrong? No error messages in console.

Comment: are you just trying to access `http://localhhost:8080`? If it is tomcat then the tomcat server is asking you to enter admin credentials

Comment: @Chaitanya, I'm using Spring Boot. I'm trying to access localhost:8080/index, mapped page

Comment: This is spring security feature. Edit you security.xml(take from web.xml) file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Search for `security properties` in your project and set

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-spring-boot-security-configuration

Check **66.1** in above link.

From Doc: **If you define a @Configuration with @EnableWebSecurity anywhere in your application it will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot**

Comment: Do you know how to ad this property with Java Class-based Configuration?

Comment: See the edit in post. define @Configuration with EnableWebSecurity in any class of your app.

Comment: And Tomcat didn't start. I'll mark answer when figure out how to apply it, then.

Answer (score 2):

I reslove it just add    `security.basic.enabled=false` in the file `application.properties` whitch you can find at `src/main/resouces` directory.
Hope this can help you:)   ps.this file is generated by IDEA, if you don't have, just create by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some basic-auth.

Basic-auth is typical configured in the `web.xml` or spring security. When you have code without spring security, then check the `web.xml` for something like:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>   
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>only registered user</description>
        <role-name>ROLE_USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

and remove it. (*But then it is likely that something that requires the authentiction will not work correct!*)

Comment: I've edited question - I'm using Spring Boot. And has no xml settings for Spring or web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem while running application from the same tutorial.

I used IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 and at the project dependencies selected  Core_Security 
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tk29N.png) while only Web_Web dependency needed.

Then I didn't really know how to delete it so I created new project without it and problem has gone.